# How do I add basic auth headers to a post request that returns html?

Tags: javascript, html, express, post

For one of the projects I am working on, there is a POST endpoint protected by basic auth that returns a HTML form. This is hosted using a express server and protected using passport's basic auth. I want to have another HTML form that has a button that, when clicked, loads that html in the browser. I tried to have a form similar to this one:

```
<form method="post" action="http://username:password@localhost:8080/endpoint">
     <input type="submit">  
</form>
```

But when the button is clicked and I check the auth headers on the server, they seem to be unset (req.headers.authorization = undefined). I know that I can set the auth headers using Javascript, but if I do that, I'm not sure how to load up the html in the browser on that page. So, how do I deal with an endpoint that requires basic auth headers, is accessed using post and returns HTML? This seems like it should be easy to do, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: The username/password in the URL [probably won't work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#Access_using_credentials_in_the_URL). You need to set the header using JavaScript.

Comment: @Sidney Is there a way to open the post endpoint in the browser? Such that the HTML is rendered?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the auth headers in javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example</title>
    <script  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="myForm">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<script type="application/javascript">
    $("#myForm").submit(function (e) {
        var url = 'http://localhost:8080/endpoint';
        var username = 'username';
        var password = 'password';
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)
            },
            data: '{ "comment" }',
            success: function (response){
                $(body).empty();
                $(body).html(response);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, but now I want to load up the response, which is HTML, in the browser, how should I do that?

Comment: In the Ajax Success callback function. Assign values of the response where ever you need to. Open your console, to see the response.

Comment: The post request returns HTML, I dont want to assign the HTML to a variable in JS,  I want to open up the HTML in the browser.

Comment: I added a way to display html. I am not sure what your response looks like.